# How to Remove Dummy Values from XML generated by XSInstance?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I am Using XSInstance Provided by in.jlibs to generate XML from XSD using Java and it is working fine, but the Problem is when i am converting XSD to XML it is automatically adding dummy values to generated XML.

Example : -

```
<Customer>
            <Address>Address1</Address>
            <Address2>Address21</Address2>
            <Address3>Address31</Address3>
            <Business_Unit>Business_Unit1</Business_Unit>
            <City>City1</City>
</Customer>
```

Here Address1, Address21, Address31, Business_Unit1, City1 are Dummy values added by XSInstance  while doing conversion, so is there any solution to generate only xml without dummy value like below.

```
     <Customer>
                <Address></Address>
                <Address2></Address2>
                <Address3></Address3>
                <Business_Unit></Business_Unit>
                <City></City>
     </Customer>
```